# Inserting timestamp in mini buffer in Emacs

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, minibuffer, time-date, format-time-string

I keep on saving various org files in their respective folders using Filename as **YYYY-MM-DD.org** files . So I ended up typing C-x C-w  2020-10-06.org at least thirty times today. Can this process be automated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
;; date
(global-set-key
 "\C-\M-d"
 (lambda (arg) (interactive "P")
   (let ((separator (pcase arg
                      ('(4) "-")
                      (0 "/")
                      (_ ""))))
     (insert
      (format-time-string (concat "%Y" separator "%m" separator "%d"))))))
```

If I press <kbd>\C-\M-d</kbd>, it inserts `20201006` into the active buffer, mini or not. If I prefix it with <kbd>C-u</kbd>, it inserts `2020-10-06`; prefixing it with <kbd>M-0</kbd> inserts `2020/10/06`.

Comment: How can I modify it to put it so that I get 2020-10-06.org

Comment: You should probably use a named function, and `format-time-string` instead.

Comment: @NickD: Updated, thanks.

Comment: @Vaibhav: Replace `"%d"` by `"%d.org"`. But I use the dates everywhere, not only when creating org files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that manufactures a filename out of today's time stamp and writes the file out:

```el
(defun write-file-timestamp ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((fname (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d.org")))
      (write-file fname t)))
```

The `t` argument in the `write-file` call asks for confirmation if the file exists already: you can omit it if you don't care, but it's probably a bad idea, since you are using the *same* file name in supposedly different directories - but if you make a mistake and you are in the wrong directory, you'll blow away your file without any warning.

You can use the function with `M-x write-file-timestamp RET` but you will probably want to add a key binding for it:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "[f12]") #'write-file-timestamp)
```

to bind it e.g. to the F12 function key.

EDIT: @choroba's answer is a direct reply to your explicit question: it inserts a timestamp into the minibuffer; it also provides a general way of inserting a timestamp anywhere.

This answer is much more limited: it targets only the implied question of automating the writing of files with a name derived from the current date.

Comment: Is there a way to accept two answers. Both the answers provide me the required solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No - you gotta choose :-) Personally, I would choose @choroba's solution because it is more general.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the answer